# How to create multiple log files of different content with log4j

Tags: log4j, testng, appender

I'm tried to create multiple log files of different content with log4j.

This is my `log4j.properties` file

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/dhanushka/Documents/log4j.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n

log4j.appender.testng=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.testng.File=/home/dhanushka/Documents/TestNGlog.log
log4j.appender.testng.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.testng.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.testng.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.testng.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, admin, stdout, testng


# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

Here is how I implemented in code.

```
public class VerifyAmenities {

private static Logger defaultLogger = Logger.getLogger("file");
private static Logger testNGlogger = Logger.getLogger("testng");
.
.
}
defaultLogger.info("This is default Logger");
testNGlogger.info("This is testNG Logger");
```

By this it creates two log files. But Both has same logs. Appreciate any ones reply.

Comment: What info you are trying to get from testng? Have you tried log4testng instead?

Comment: No i don't want another logger. want to attach separate log file of testNG results with log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way of doing this.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout, file

log4j.category.testngLogger=DEBUG, testng
log4j.additivity.testngLogger=false
```

In `rootLogger`, that is like a father of all logs. It inherit by default. Root logger option should be like that. 

If you `additivity` set to `false` it will never goes to `rootLogger`

In `log4j.xml` file it will goes like this.

```
<logger name="testngLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="testngLogger" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
</root>
```